# Twilio Video - Catch "Ringing" event at web

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, videocall

I need to show the 'Ringing...' text on the web if the target starts ringing for that I need to capture the ringing event somewhere.

Here is my function:

```
registerRoomEvents(room: Video.Room) {
    room
      .on('participantConnected', this.addParticipant)
      .on('participantDisconnected', (participant) => {
        this.removeAwaitingParticipant(participant.identity);
      })
      .on('disconnected', this.onRoomDisconnection)
      .on('dominantSpeakerChanged', this.onDominantSpeakerChanged);
  }
```

Please help how can I capture the **ringing** event?

Comment: This has been implemented using websocket. Suppose if mobile start getting the notification it triggers the socket event. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be using the Twilio Video API, which doesn't have a *ringing* event.

When you connect to a Twilio Video room, you connect immediately. There's no concept of ringing or waiting to connect for any reason, unless you have built that into your own application.

All [the events that a Video Room fires can be found in the documentation](https://sdk.twilio.com/js/video/releases/2.21.3/docs/Room.html).